# PyQt QLineEdit and 'paste' event?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I searched everywhere but couldn't find an example on triggering a slot/event when text gets pasted in an PyQt4 QLineEdit ?

Comment: There is no paste signal or event in Qt. You can use `textChanged` signal and check if new content is the same as clipboard content using `QClipboard` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following code to your `MyForm` class:

Inside `__init__()`

```
self.ui.lineEdit_URL.textChanged.connect(self.valueChanged)
```

Define new method:

```
def valueChanged(self, text):
     if QtGui.QApplication.clipboard().text() == text:
         self.pasteEvent(text)
```

Define another method:

```
def pasteEvent(self, text):
    # this is your paste event, whenever any text is pasted in the
    # 'lineEdit_URL', this method gets called.
    # 'text' is the newly pasted text.

    print text
```

Comment: FWIW, it seems to me that this `pasteEvent` will get called whenever the line edit's text is *changed* (e.g. a keyboard keypress). That's quite different than only getting called when texted is *pasted*, which is how I interpret the OP's question.

Comment: I stand corrected. However, the `pasteEvent` will still get called if it just so happens that the widget's text matches the clipboard exactly. However, this does not necessarily mean that the text got there because it was pasted. Although maybe that doesn't matter for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define it yourself by overriding "keyPressEvent". For Example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class NoteText(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super (NoteText, self).__init__(parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Paste):
            self.setText("Bye")

class Test(QtGui.QWidget):
  def __init__( self, parent=None):
      super(Test, self).__init__(parent)

      le = QtGui.QLineEdit()
      nt = NoteText(le)

      layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
      layout.addWidget(nt)
      self.setLayout(layout)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWidget = Test()
myWidget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I am importing the ui from a different file as `class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  
    
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.threads = []
    self.ui.pushButton_Start.clicked.connect(self.thread_start)` can you pls. post an newbie friendly example for this?

Comment: Something like `self.ui.lineEdit_URL.textChanged.connect(self.KeyDown) def KeyDown(self, event):
      # implement the method here
      if event.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Paste):
            print 'Pasted'` but this results in `AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'matches'
`

Comment: @Stacked. Please don't spam the comments with code dumps. If you have code that is relevant to your question, add it to the question itself.

Comment: @ekhumoro: well, strictly speaking, these are short snippets which are OK in comments IMHO. OPs cannot always judge the usefulness of such things, and comments can be always cleaned up. I find it myself useful when I get short snippets or error messages like this that moves the issue forward.

Comment: @LaszloPapp. They would be much more useful in the question, which is currently only one sentence long. More to the point, they don't directly address this answer, and hence are not constructive in this context.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I guess we will need to agree to disagree. IMO, the question should not be edited by every random trial and run. Comments and chats suit that need better IMHO. Once, there is something more stable and robust to write about, the real posts can be updated accordingly. In fact, I dislike when people break the history, and the flow is not so apparent. That is awkward IMHO, and that is the case when a comment discussion, etc, is broken in half at some point with a question update. Once the comments reached a conclusion, they can be cleaned up, and the Q/As can be updated.

Comment: @LaszloPapp. As on a few occasions before, I don't think we really disagree by _much_. Code snippets in comments are fine, as long as they are relevant; and by itself, just adding more code to a question won't necessarily make it better, as you say. And I agree that maintaining the integrity of the original question is very important.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I would also prefer not to break the history of conversation and create confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the CTRL-V and then process the text before pasting it into the Edit.

```
import pyperclip

class MyLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super (MyLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() == Qt.KeyboardModifier.ControlModifier and event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_V:
            clipboard_content = pyperclip.paste()
            self.setText('hi' + clipboard_content)
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
```