# how can I oveload paste on a QtextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextedit

I want to paste in a QTextEdit an text with an certain font size, ex. 14

I made an app that replace a paraghaph sign with a blank space, like in 
[PyQt QLineEdit and 'paste' event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089316/pyqt-qlineedit-and-paste-event)

On def `__init__(self)` I code:

```
self.textEdit.textChanged.connect(self.valueChanged)
```

then

```
def valueChanged(self, text):
    if QtGui.QApplication.clipboard().text() == text:
        self.pasteEvent(text)
```

and then

```
def pasteEvent(self, text):
    text.toUpper()
```

```
TypeError: valueChanged() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: This is Qt5 code isn't it? I think connects work differently in Qt4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the previous question that links you use a QLineEdit that has the [`void QLineEdit::textChanged(const QString &text)`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#text-prop) signal that carries the text, but in the case of QTextEdit there is a signal with the same name [`void textChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#html-prop) but it does not carry the text so that is the cause of the error. The solution for that case is to obtain the text using the object and not through the signal.

```py
def valueChanged(self):
    if QtGui.QApplication.clipboard().text() == self.textEdit.text():
        self.pasteEvent(text)
```

Although if your goal is to change the size of the font then your previous logic does not work since you are detecting the event after the text is pasted, if you want to modify something during the paste then you must override the [insertFromMimeData()](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#insertFromMimeData) method:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class TextEdit(QtGui.QTextEdit):
    def insertFromMimeData(self, source):
        last_font = self.currentFont()

        new_font = QtGui.QFont(last_font)
        new_font.setPointSize(14)
        self.setCurrentFont(new_font)
        super(TextEdit, self).insertFromMimeData(source)
        self.setCurrentFont(last_font)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = TextEdit()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```